# qmake is enabling both clang++ and g++ at the same time

Tags: c++, linux, qt-creator, qmake

Regardless of my .pro file contents, both clang++ and g++ keep being used:

```
linux-clang++
{
    message("Using clang++")
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Weverything
}
linux-g++
{
    message("Using g++")
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra
}
```

I've also tried checking `QMAKE_CXX` through `contains(QMAKE_CXX, clang++)` and `equals(QMAKE_CXX = clang++)`, as per the qmake documentation, but I get the same output regardless:

```
Project MESSAGE: Using clang++
Project MESSAGE: Using g++
```

`message($$QMAKESPEC)` outputs `Project MESSAGE: /usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++`, and the build settings also say `-spec linux-g++`, but it seems to keep having clang enabled.

The reverse is also true: changing my default compiler in QtCreator to clang, and setting `QMAKE_CXX = clang++` results in g++ still being used too.

Can only assume I've missed something somewhere?

Comment: How many Makefiles qmake generates for you? What's inside them?

Comment: Only 1 makefile is generated, as desired, and it's all normal (-spec linux-g++, etc.). This can be detected prior to building though; editing the .pro file and saving, qtcreator auto-parses, and outputs both messages. Even when adding `equals(QMAKE_CXX, "blah")`, it still enters its scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just figured it out. The curly-brackets must remain on the same line as the statement, otherwise qmake interprets it as a blank statement that's always true.

For example, I tested:

```
linux-clang++
{
    message("linux-clang++:Using clang++")
}
linux-g++
{
    message("linux-g++:Using g++")
}
equals(QMAKE_CXX, g++)
{
    message("equals:Using g++")
}
equals(QMAKE_CXX, clang++)
{
    message("equals:Using clang++")
}
equals(QMAKE_CXX, "blah")
{
    message("equals:Using blah")
}
```

and this output:

```
Project MESSAGE: linux-clang++:Using clang++
Project MESSAGE: linux-g++:Using g++
Project MESSAGE: equals:Using g++
Project MESSAGE: equals:Using clang++
Project MESSAGE: equals:Using blah
```

With the aforementioned adjustment, it works fine:

```
linux-clang++ {
    message("linux-clang++:Using clang++")
}
linux-g++ {
    message("linux-g++:Using g++")
}
equals(QMAKE_CXX, g++) {
    message("equals:Using g++")
}
equals(QMAKE_CXX, clang++) {
    message("equals:Using clang++")
}
equals(QMAKE_CXX, "blah") {
    message("equals:Using blah")
}

Project MESSAGE: linux-g++:Using g++
Project MESSAGE: equals:Using g++
```

Comment: The form using `{`...`}` is designed for multiple lines of conditional stuff - for a _single_ line I believe a colon `:` after the condition is enough for a single line _(on the same line)_ of action.  It is however also possible to follow/change the closing `}` form to an `} else {` (all on the same line) to have something done if the condition is **not** true, with the else action laid out in the same way (with a closing `}`) - I am not sure if it is possible to have a single line form for one but a multi-line form for the other in an "if/else" construct though...